# add number beginning of line

Tags: awk, sed

I'm trying to add an incrementing value to a file based on the value
e.g. which changes anytime it finds 'E' (this can be replaced with any value)
From some online research I've tried:

```
awk '/E/{sub("E", "E"++v)}1' output.txt > output2.txt
```

but that only adds an incremental value after the 'E' itself.
No, this is not a school assignment, this data will next be ingested into a MySQL table with that value being the ID field. Note: the 'E' will always be present at the End of the dataset. This file (a very larger version) will be ingested into MySQL table, for a word unscrambler application.

Sample file: output.txt

```
aaa
aba
acaE
baa
bab
badE
caa
cab
cdeE
ddd
```

Sample file: desired

```
1aaa
1aba
1acaE
2baa
2bab
2badE
3caa
3cab
3cdeE
4ddd
```

Comment: You say "the value". Which value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it thus:

```
awk '{print i $0}; /E$/{i++}' i=1 file
```

We set `i=1` as the initial value, because by default it is unset. `{print i $0}` prints `i` and the whole line `$0`. Then, just check if the line matches `E` and increment `i` in that case.

A very similar alternative proposed by αғsнιη is

```
awk '{print i+1 $0}; /E$/{i++}' file
```

summing `1` to `i` so that we do not have to initially set `i=1`.

Comment: You can remove the `,` instead of overriding `OFS` too.

Comment: as well as removing `i=1`- `awk '{ print i+1 $0} /E$/ { i++ }' infile` or alternatively `awk '{ $0=i+1 $0} /E$/ { i++ }1' infile`